# jQuery image hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, hover

I'm trying to achieve [this effect](http://stuff.maikeldaloo.com/jq_img_hover/mousescroll.swf) with jQuery.

I wrote some of the code, but it's buggy (move to the bottom-right corder and you'll see).
[check it out](http://stuff.maikeldaloo.com/jq_img_hover/)

Basically, if there's an already-built jQuery plugin that you know of that does this, I'd be very happy using it, if not, any help with my formula would be appreciated. This is what I get for not paying attention in Maths classes :)

Thanks in advance.

Maikel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overall I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$.fn.sexyImageHover = function() { 
    var p = this, // parent
        i = this.children('img'); // image

    i.load(function(){
        // get image and parent width/height info
        var pw = p.width(),
            ph = p.height(),
            w = i.width(),
            h = i.height();

        // check if the image is actually larger than the parent
        if (w > pw || h > ph) {
            var w_offset = w - pw,
                h_offset = h - ph;

            // center the image in the view by default
            i.css({ 'margin-top':(h_offset / 2) * -1, 'margin-left':(w_offset / 2) * -1 });

            p.mousemove(function(e){
                var new_x = 0 - w_offset * e.offsetX / w,
                    new_y = 0 - h_offset * e.offsetY / h;

                i.css({ 'margin-top':new_y, 'margin-left':new_x });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BeCF9/1/).

Notable changes:

- `new_x` and `new_y` should be divided by the *images* height/width, not the container's height/width, which is wider.
- `this` is already a jQuery object in a `$.fn.plugin` function, no need to wrap it.

  - `i` and `p` were also jQuery objects, no need to keep wrapping them
- no need to bind `mousemove` on `mouseenter` (which rebinds) the `mousemove` will only occur when you're inside anyway.

Comment: Aside from the slowly coming to the stop, it isn't exactly like the example. I can't quit describe it but something is off.

Comment: @Glenn - it doesn't have the easing, it's definitely a more simplified version, I was just showing how to fix the current code :)

Comment: it is more complicated to add easing?

Comment: @Maikel - definitely, you'd have to calculate mouse velocity over a time period...but for a small image I don't think it'd be worth it.

Comment: It's odd.. but that example just doesn't seem to work for me on Firefox. `new_x` and `new_y` are returning `NaN` inside the mousemove event

Comment: @Nick, thanks for your help, but do you know why it kinda freaks out when u move to the edge? happens to me in chrome

Comment: @Yi, i actually just checked my code too.. no good in FF.. found an alternative though: http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/minizoompan/

Comment: @Maikel - because the offset container is changing, try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BeCF9/3/

Comment: @nick , one quick quesiton , you are calling the function on document.ready , is it going to fire for all the images in a page.

Comment: @gov - yup, because it binds for the `.load()` event, you can alternatively call it without the bind on `window.load()`, but that's not safe for a plugin, since that event may have already passed.

Answer (score 3):

Nick Craver beat me to an answer by about 10 minutes, but this is my code for this, using `background-image` to position the image instead of an actual image.

```
var img = $('#outer'),
    imgWidth = 1600,
    imgHeight = 1200,
    eleWidth = img.width(),
    eleHeight = img.height(),
    offsetX = img.offset().left,
    offsetY = img.offset().top,
    moveRatioX = imgWidth / eleWidth - 1,
    moveRatioY = imgHeight / eleHeight - 1;


img.mousemove(function(e){
    var x = imgWidth - ((e.pageX - offsetX) * moveRatioX),
        y = imgHeight - ((e.pageY - offsetY) * moveRatioY);
    this.style.backgroundPosition =  x + 'px ' + y + 'px';
});
```

The *huge* amount of variables are there because the `mousemove` event handler has to be as efficient as possible. It's slightly more restrictive, because you need to know the dimensions, but I think the code can be easily altered to work with `img`s for which the size can be calculated easily.

A simple demo of this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/fq2te/1/

Comment: Should note this has a few restrictions over the original though, for example you need to know the dimensions.  That being said, it's a good alternative for many situations, +1.