# Java script image hover effect

Tags: javascript, css

I want to get this desired hover image effect?

http://www.colingrist.com/

I was wondering if anyone knew the code?
When you hover the image it moves.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "free code" website. You should ask problems you have in solving problems.

Comment: Oh man, it's also a DUPE! [jQuery image hover effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161154/jquery-image-hover-effect?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to this :) You need the jquery library of course

http://jsfiddle.net/yFMeJ/

```
jQuery("#banner").mousemove(
        function(e){
            /* Work out mouse position */
            var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
            var xPos = e.pageX - offset.left;
            var yPos = e.pageY - offset.top;

            /* Get percentage positions */
            var mouseXPercent = Math.round(xPos / jQuery(this).width() * 100);
            var mouseYPercent = Math.round(yPos / jQuery(this).height() * 100);

            /* Position Each Layer */
            jQuery(this).children('img').each(
                function(){
                    var diffX = jQuery('#Parallax').width() - jQuery(this).width();
                    var diffY = jQuery('#Parallax').height() - jQuery(this).height();

                    var myX = diffX * (mouseXPercent / 1500); //) / 100) / 2;


                    var myY = diffY * (mouseYPercent / 1080);


                    var cssObj = {
                        'left': myX + 'px',
                        'top': myY + 'px'
                    }
                    //jQuery(this).css(cssObj);
                    jQuery(this).animate({left: myX, top: myY},{duration: 50, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});

                }
            );

        }
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

[How do I view source of a webpage?](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm)

```
// Paralax Homepage Banner

    jQuery("#banner").mousemove(
        function(e){
            /* Work out mouse position */
            var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
            var xPos = e.pageX - offset.left;
            var yPos = e.pageY - offset.top;

            /* Get percentage positions */
            var mouseXPercent = Math.round(xPos / jQuery(this).width() * 100);
            var mouseYPercent = Math.round(yPos / jQuery(this).height() * 100);

            /* Position Each Layer */
            jQuery(this).children('img').each(
                function(){
                    var diffX = jQuery('#Parallax').width() - jQuery(this).width();
                    var diffY = jQuery('#Parallax').height() - jQuery(this).height();

                    var myX = diffX * (mouseXPercent / 1500); //) / 100) / 2;


                    var myY = diffY * (mouseYPercent / 1080);


                    var cssObj = {
                        'left': myX + 'px',
                        'top': myY + 'px'
                    }
                    //jQuery(this).css(cssObj);
                    jQuery(this).animate({left: myX, top: myY},{duration: 50, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});

                }
            );

        }
    );
```

http://www.colingrist.com/wp-content/themes/mill/scripts/functions.js

Comment: Seriously good question... You beat me to the answer by three nanoseconds! Well done.

Comment: @Lance good thing it was Wordpress and not a real site with minified/compressed JS! ;-)

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer?!

Comment: I did downvote you. I don't think we should help people asking this kind of questions. This also could be a commment.

Comment: @Mohsen I agree with you, and I'm surprised the question hasn't been closed already.

Comment: Relax it was my first time using the site.